# Add a column with the current timestamp to a table in Hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, sql-insert

I'm trying to add a column called tstamp to a table that I've created. The column is to have the current timestamp in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd' populating each row.

I initially created the table from another table (table1) using the statement:

```
create location2.table2
as (select *
    from location1.table1
    );
```

I then used the alter table statement to add a field called tstamp to table2 using the code:

```
alter table location2.table2
add columns (tstamp date)
```

and I can see that this has successfully added a column to table2 named tstamp and populated each row of this table as null. I am now trying to insert the current date into every row in the field tstamp but am struggling to do so. I've tried using the insert into statement as:

```
insert into location2.table2 (tstamp)
values (to_date(current_timestamp()))
```

but get the error "Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values". I then also tried to add just a string and replaced the function with '2019-07-25'. Doing this added a new row to my table with null values in every column except tstamp which had a value '2019-07-25'. I'm now confused as it appears my approach was not the right one for the problem and am unsure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create location2.table2 as (select current_date as tstamp,*  from location1.table1 );